# Is it possible to manipulate the target window of a form using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I got this question regarding the forms target and its target window.. lets say we have this **Html.BeginForm**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestHtmlRedirect", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {@target="_blank", @id = "tagging_frm", @class = "form-horizontal row-border" }))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Html PsBk Click" />
}
```

normally upon clicking the submit button it will trigger a new tab, my question is
**How, or is it Possible to append something to the newly created tab of this form?**

for example i want to append a loading gif on that newly created tab by the parent tab.

Comment: $("#dom").append("#anotherdom");

Comment: Append what to the tab? If you want to add html to the resulting tab, you need to give it a name - for example change _blank to _mywin and if the action of the form is the same origin as the script, you could possibly do `var myWin = window.open("","_mywin");` to get the handle and then do `$(mywin).find('#somediv').append('some stuff');` - Now you have changed the question, I would change the whole thing to open the window, add the loader and then target the form to an iFrame

Comment: @mplungjan but the problem here is it is generated by the form. is it possible to append something on that tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the actions and scripts are all from the same server/origin, you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tagging_frm").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    var w=window.open("",this.target);
    w.document.write('<div id="container"><img src="loading.gif"/></div>');
    w.document.close();
    $.post(this.action,function(data) {
      w.document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=data;
    });
  });
});
```

To load a csv or pdf try this alternative

```
$(function() {
  $("#tagging_frm").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    var w=window.open("",this.target);
    w.document.write('<form id="myForm" action="'+this.action+'" target="myframe" method="post"></form><img id="loading" src="loading.gif"/><iframe name="myframe" onload="document.getElementById(\'loading\').style.display=\'none\'"></iframe>');
    w.document.close();
    w.document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: i think i should remove the _mywin on the form??

Comment: Not if you want to target an iFrame. If all the script and form action is from the same origin, ajax the data and show it. Then you can do whatever you want while it is loading

Comment: i tried your code it opened 2 windows. the ones who is appended and other that is blank

Comment: There is likely a timing issue. We would need to defer the submission until the iframe exists. Can you answer me if all scripts actions and forms live on the same sever?

Comment: yes. I want to achieve is to append the iframe on the tab that the form produced but i cant do it using any jquery. how can we use that tab or is there a way to say for example $(_tab).append("<div>Hello World</div>")

Comment: how would it be.. I preserve that new tab in order for the generated pdf report to show on the tab, by the way its for reporting purpose. I need to show loading page before the report loads

Comment: Please see my update which assumes form and script and action all are from the same site

Comment: it doesn't hit the controller.. But it is an elegant solution

Comment: Ah, I would need to see the rendered HTML since I do not use your type of server framework

Comment: thanks bro it did the job. The only thing left for me is how to interpret the return type which is a file with .csv format and .pdf. Thanks. This is awesome. The $.post returns a file. which is the main report.

Comment: yeah but ive done that before. important is you gave me an awesome workaround

Comment: Have a look at my update which may work better for PDF and such